# Kivy runs weird on anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, kivy

I have a question about kivy and it runs weird on anaconda

First weird thing: I have to add  into the kivy file then run it and delete the <> from the MenuScreen in the kivy code and run the file again in order for my code to runs like I want. if I don't do this the code will give `FactoryException: Unknown class <MenuScreen>`

Second weird thing is that after I end kivy and run it again it doesn't let me change screen on the app, I have to restart the shell and do everything like the (first weird thing above) for it to switch screen and run properly.

Here is the code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
kv = Builder.load_file('mymain.kv')

class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass

class SecondWindow(Screen):
    point = ObjectProperty(None)
    note = ObjectProperty(None)
    def pressed(self):
        ''' this fuction is the function of the good action button'''
        point1 = self.point.text
        Note1 = self.note.text
        try:
            point1 = int(point1)
            print("You just got: ",point1)
            print('Note of this action: ')
            print(Note1)
        except:
            if point1 == '':
                print('please enter something')
            else:
                print("point should be a number")
        #print(point1, Note1)
        self.point.text = ""
        self.note.text = ''
        #return grid

    def increased(self):
        ''' this function is to increase the mark'''
        point2 = self.point.text
        try:
            point2 = int(float(point2))+1
            print('increase point is', point2)
            #self.point.text = str(point2)
        except:
            point2 = 1
            print('your point is: ','1')
        self.point.text = str(point2)
    def decreased(self):
        ''' this function decrease the point'''
        point3 = self.point.text
        try:
            point3 = int(float(point3))-1
            print('decrease point is', point3)
            #self.point.text = str(point3)
        except:
            point3 = -1
            print('your point is: ', '-1')
        self.point.text = str(point3)


class MenuScreen(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyMainApp().run()
```

Here is the mymain.kv

```
MenuScreen:
    MainWindow:
    SecondWindow:

<MainWindow>:

    name: "main"

    GridLayout:

        cols: 1

        Button:

            text: 'Good'
            on_release: app.root.current = 'second'
        Button:
            text: 'Bad' #not doing anything yet
<SecondWindow>:

    name: 'second'
    point: point
    note: note
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        size: root.width, root.height

        GridLayout:

            cols: 3



            Label:

                text: 'Good Point: '



            TextInput:

                id: point

                multiline: False

            GridLayout:

                cols: 1

                Button:

                    text: 'up'

                    on_press: root.increased()

                Button:

                    text: 'down'

                    on_press: root.decreased()



        Label:

            text: 'Note: '



        TextInput:

            id: note

            multiline: True
        Button:
            text: ' submit'
            on_press: root.pressed()
```

please help me. Idk why kivy runs like this.
 Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `mymain.kv` is getting loaded twice. Kivy will automatically load a `kv` file if it is named correctly (as your is - See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.load_kv)), and you are also loading it via a `Builder.load_string()` call. The fix is to remove the line:

```
kv = Builder.load_file('mymain.kv')
```

and simplify your `App` class to:

```
class MyMainApp(App):
    pass
    # def build(self):
    #     return kv
```

Comment: I don't think that is the problem since I name it different before and the same problem happen that is why I tried to name it the same and see if the result is different and the same problem happened

Answer (score 0):

in `mymain.kv` change:

```
MenuScreen:
    MainWindow:
    SecondWindow:
```

to

```
<MenuScreen>:
    MainWindow:
    SecondWindow:
```

Comment: that's the first weird thing